# User Defined numpy 2D array in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to code up for a user defined 2D array in Python using Numpy.

I tried the below Code, but it is not working for some reason.

```
import numpy as np
x=list()
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
for i in range(n*m):
    z=int(input())
    x.append(z)
x=np.reshape((n,m))
print(x)
```

In the code I am trying to take a list as an input from user which is containing a total of `n*m` elements and then using reshape to reshape the array into a dimension of `(n,m)`.

Can Someone point out the error I am making in the code also a correct way to implement a user defined 2d array in numpy?

Comment: You should tell us what the error is. Anyway, you want `np.reshape(x, (n, m))`.

Comment: @bgse thank you very much